# WPF TreeView with properties as second level

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I´m working on a WPF project with a Treeview - and the following Model objects

```
PersonModel
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }


EmployeeModel : PersonModel
    public int MonthlySalary { get; set; }
    public int MonthlyHours { get; set; }

MainWindowViewModel
   public ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel> Employees
    {
        get { return _employees; }
        set { _employees = value; }
    }
```

MainWindow XAML

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding FullName}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

So fare I´m getting a list of epmloyees (the fullname) and what I would like to do is to have MonthlySalary and MonthlyHours as children like:

```
- John Doe
  - 30 hours
  - 5.000 dollars
- Jane Doe
  - 40 hours
  - 10.000 dollars
```

Any suggestions to how I should setup the XAML in order to list data the way I want to?
Regards

Comment: A TreeViewItem can have another TreeViewitem as a child : <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding FullName}"><TreeViewItem Header="{Binding MonthlySalary}" /><TreeViewItem Header="{Binding MonthlyHours}" /></TreeViewItem>

Answer (score 1):

Here's some XAML for you:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HoursTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:EmployeeModel}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding MonthlyHours}" />
                <Run Text=" hours" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SalaryTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:EmployeeModel}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding MonthlySalary}" />
                <Run Text=" dollars" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
                    <TreeViewItem
                        Header="{Binding FullName}"
                        IsExpanded="True">
                        <TreeViewItem
                            Header="{Binding}"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HoursTemplate}" />
                        <TreeViewItem
                            Header="{Binding}"
                            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource SalaryTemplate}" />
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I hope this helps.